# Error starting developer studio WSO2 Api manager (eclipse)

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-appm

i am trying to use developer studio with wso2 AM 3.1.0 but i have an error executing it.
The Developer studio version is 2.6.0 and I downloaded it from here:
https://wso2.com/api-management/tooling/

this appears to me in the terminal:

```
(Eclipse:6268): GLib-CRITICAL **: 19:04:19.926: g_base64_encode_step: assertion 'in != NULL' failed
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Logback config file: /home/franco/eclipse- 
workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration/logback.1.8.3.20180227 2137.xml
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in 
[bundleresource://997.fwk10624116:1/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in 
[bundleresource://997.fwk10624116:2/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration: Initializing logback
Gtk-Message: 19:04:24.812: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
```

and the log showed this:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2020-06-16 00:05:56.495
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/PreDestroy
    at 
org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.disposed(InjectorImpl.java:450)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.Requestor.disposed(Requestor.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.ContextObjectSupplier$ContextInjectionListener.update(ContextObjectSupplier.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.update(TrackableComputationExt.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.TrackableComputationExt.handleInvalid(TrackableComputationExt.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.EclipseContext.dispose(EclipseContext.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.dispose(EclipseContextOSGi.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.contexts.osgi.EclipseContextOSGi.bundleChanged(EclipseContextOSGi.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:908)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor.publishModuleEvent(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.publishEvent(Module.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:202)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PreDestroy cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:395)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try using **WSO2 Integration Studio IDE** downloaded from https://wso2.com/integration/integration-studio/.

I too get the following error when trying to run Developer Studio downloaded from this link https://wso2.com/api-management/tooling/.

You can follow [this documentation](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/creating-and-uploading-using-integration-studio/) to use Integration Studio for creating and uploading mediation extensions for WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0.